# Find a point equidistant from two points and a line

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given a line: $x-\frac{2}{2} = y-\frac{1}{6} = z+\frac{2}{2}$ and two points $P_1(1,1,0)$ and $P_2(0,1,-1)$, identify the point $V$ which resides on the line and is equidistant from $P_1$, and $P_2$.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE.  Questions are received better if you explain what you've tried and where you are stuck.  Assuming you're on a plane in euclidian space, there's a line that runs equidistant to any two points. It's orthogonal to the line between those points. Find where it intersects the other line.

Answer (score 0):

The locus of all the point $P(x,y)$ such that $PP_1=PP_2$ is the plane
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=x^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2\to x+z=0$$
Find the intersection between the line and the plane solving the system
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{x-2}{2} =\frac{y-1}{6}\\
\frac{x-2}{2} = \frac{z+2}{2}\\
x+z=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
Solution should be $V(0,-5,0)$